# executing python throw ajax , import does not work

Tags: php, python, ajax, import, directory

i'm actually making ajax request that call a php file which call a python file. My main problem is with the imports in the python scripts. I actually work on local.

I'm on linux. When i do "$ php myScript.php"  ( which call python script inside ) it's work but when it come from the ajax call then the import of the python files does not work. So i moved some libraries in the current folder of the php and python script. First the import will only work if the library is in a folder, impossible to call a function from my other python script. Then i can't do " import tweepy " even if the library is in the current folder. But for pymongo its worked because I do " from pymongo import MongoClient ". All my script worked when call from php or when executed with python throw command line.

Thoses libraries are also in my current python folder on linux but throw ajax call it never go there. I specify this at the beginning of each python file "#!/usr/bin/env python2.7"

Here the path of my files 
folder 
----- script.php 
----- script.py 
----- pymongo[FOLDER] 
----- tweepy[FOLDER]

Ps : Sorry english is not my main language

Comment: How do you installed **tweepy** and **pymongo**?

Comment: I use pip : pip install tweepy

But after that i copy the library in the folder of my project as i show you up there

Comment: I also check with : print(platform.python_version()) , it use the version of python 2.7 which is normal and the library are well install for this one

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeed. In fact tweepy use the library call "six" which is not in my current folder. So i import all the python library in my folder, so i get no more error. 
But i still don't understand why python does not go search the library in his normal folder instead in the current folder.